# Xcode 6 – Unified storyboard & Size Classes

Tags: xcode, autolayout, ios8, xcode6

How does auto-layout work to create interfaces in Xcode 6 beta? What are different size classes & how do they work? How to use the "Resizable Unified Storyboard" to create universal iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about "Size Classes" introduced in XCode6.

A size class is a new technology used by iOS to allow you to custom your app for a given device class, based on its orientation and screen size.

There are presently four size classes.[image]

At any time your device is going to have a horizontal size class and a vertical size class.

You don't need to worry about device size. Whether it is iPhone 4s, 5 or mighty iPhone 6. UI would be handled automatically for you...

For more info read [this article.](http://carpeaqua.com/2014/06/14/thinking-in-terms-of-ios-8-size-classes/)

See this WWDC Video for more clarity..[Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)

Answer (score 0):

With that new feature only aspect ratios are defined. Click at the button "blue" area and you will see the description for the aspect:

wAny hRegular -> For all regular height layouts (e.g. iPhones in portrait, and iPads in portrait or landscape)